What is a simple explanation and example of de Bruijn indices?

In order to find the recurrence formula for the number of λ-terms of a given size, we make use of the representation of variables in λ-terms by de Bruijn indices. Recall that a de Bruijn index is a natural number which replaces a term variable and enumerates the number of λ’s encountered on the way between the variable and the λ which binds the latter.

Wikipedia says:

Formally, λ-terms (M, N, ...) written using de Bruijn indices have the following syntax (parentheses allowed freely):
M, N, ... ::= n | M N | λ M where n—natural numbers greater than 0—are the variables.

I suppose I do not understand why the definition needs multiple lambda terms M, N, …. Wouldn’t you just use de Bruijn indices for a single lambda term, such as lambda x . x + x? $n$ is a natural number that acts as the variable. I don’t understand the | M N | $\lambda$ M part.

A variable n is bound if it is in the scope of at least n binders (λ); otherwise it is free. The binding site for a variable n is the nth binder it is in the scope of, starting from the innermost binder.


In this paper, we assume the combinatorial model in which the size of
each occurrence of abstraction or application is counted as 1, while
the size of variables (de Bruijn indices) as 0. This method is a
realistic model of the complexity of λ-terms and allows us to derive
the recurrences very naturally.

Why is it necessary or valuable to count the size of variables/their de Bruijn indices as 0?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.2610.pdf


I suppose I do not understand why the definition needs multiple lambda terms M, N, …. Wouldn’t you just use de Bruijn indices for a single lambda term, such as lambda x . x + x?

This is merely a question of notation. When we write $M, N ::= …$, it means that we are giving an inductive definition, and when $M$ or $N$ appears inside the definition, it means "some already constructed term".
In other words, this definition can be rephrased as:
We define the set of λ-terms inductively by the three rules:

Every natural number is a λ-term,
For all λ-terms $M$ and $N$, there is a λ-term written $M N$,
For all λ-term $M$, $λ M$ is a λ-term.

Basically, this just means "λ-terms are finite trees, where leaves are labeled by integers, and nodes can be of two types, application with two children, or λ-abstraction with one child". The way to phrase inductive definitions isn't very standardized. Some would write this as $Λ ::= n ∈ ℕ | Λ Λ | λ Λ$, using the symbol $Λ$ to mean "a λ-term already constructed". This more closely resembles formal grammars, but it can also be slightly confusing since $Λ Λ$ does not require the two λ-terms to be the same. I think that's the reason why other people prefer this style with $M, N ::= …$


In this paper, we assume the combinatorial model in which the size of each occurrence of abstraction or application is counted as 1, while the size of variables (de Bruijn indices) as 0. This method is a realistic model of the complexity of λ-terms and allows us to derive the recurrences very naturally.

Why is it necessary or valuable to count the size of variables/their de Bruijn indices as 0?

You're probably thinking that the more natural model would be to count the size of a variable as 1, but in fact this doesn't really matter, because you cannot have many variables without also having many applications, so if a term is "big" by this measure, it is also big by the measure defined in the paper. I'll let you prove the precise bound as an exercise.
